# List class element(index).fadetoggle(some speed) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 lists of class items

```
var listEditCommitLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-comment-link');
var listEditCommitWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-commit-wrapper');
```

links and wrappers

```
<a href="#" class="edit-commit-link">Edit</a>
<div class="edit-commit-wrapper">
 ..
</div>
```

style

```
.edit-commit-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

On default each wrapper is hidden, and should fadetoggle on a link click (with the same list index nr)

But for some reason this isn't working out for me. 
The js for running through the list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listEditCommitLinks.length; i++) {

    listEditCommitLinks[i].onclick = function () {
        listEditCommitWrappers[i].fadeToggle(200);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: listEditCommitWrappers[i].fadeToggle is not a function

Added

[how the divs look like](http://pastebin.ca/3287554)

Is there a way to fix this? A jQuery solution is also good (I tried this before js but wasn't working out either). Thanks

Comment: Style should be `display: none`, not `display="none"`

Comment: @Phil sorry misspelled my post

Comment: Your question HTML doesn't look **anything** like the HTML in your pasetbin. How can you expect help if you don't provide the right information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, `fadeToggle` is a jQuery instance method and the items in `listEditCommitWrappers` are **not** jQuery objects. How about...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.edit-commit-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.edit-commit-wrapper').fadeToggle(200);
    });
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/next/

Working jsFiddle ~ http://jsfiddle.net/t4nh85cm/

---

To make it work with your pastebin HTML, you could try something like this although I feel it's getting messy

```
$(this).closest('.row').next('.edit-commit-wrapper').fadeToggle(200);
```

See https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: this instead of the whole js loop? Doesn't seems to work:(.

Comment: Explain what *"doesn't seem to work"* actually means. Do you get errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Ow sorry, now errors at all, i'am debugging atm for checking what is does (or doesn't). I think it could be done by the solution/link you gave me. I think the next isn't finding the next because there are some nested divs (not sure(?)). I added a pastabin code of how the divs really looks like

Comment: @JimVercoelen it was because your code had `edit-comment-link` but your HTML has `edit-commit-link`. I've fixed it in my answer

Comment: ow that was a bad one, but now it is working like you said thanks for that.

Comment: Not sure how downvoted but if this is for the misspelled code, sorry for that! It's already a long day for me right now, but ill keep in mind the next time!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop isn't work properly as you thought, because when the for ended, all the I is actually (listEditCommitLinks.length+1). Not the 0, 1, 2... you can write a closure like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < listEditCommitLinks.length; i++) 
{
    listEditCommitLinks[i].onclick = (function (a) 
    {
        return function () 
        {
            listEditCommitWrappers[a].fadeToggle(200);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Very good point but the `listEditCommitWrappers[a]` still needs to be wrapped in a jQuery object for it to get `fadeToggle`